# OpenCL directories declared invalid after using them once

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I have a strange problem with my OpenCL project. When I add the directories to the compiler(compiler is Dev-C++) it works at first. Problem is if I close Dev-C++ and open it up again all the directories are declared invalid. If I delete them and add them again they seem to work. Why is this happening. Here is my code if it helps:

```
// Copyright (c) 2010 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. All rights   reserved.
//
// A minimalist OpenCL program.
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CL/cl_ext.h>
#define NWITEMS 512

// A simple memset kernel
const char *source =
  "__kernel void memset( __global uint *dst ) \n"
  "{ \n"
  " dst[get_global_id(0)] = get_global_id(0); \n"
  "} \n";
int main(int argc, char ** argv, global_work_size)
{
  // 1. Get a platform.
  cl_platform_id platform;
  clGetPlatformIDs( 1, &platform, NULL );
  // 2. Find a gpu device.
  cl_device_id device;
  clGetDeviceIDs( platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
          1,
          &device,
          NULL);
  // 3. Create a context and command queue on that device.
  cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL,
                    1,
                    &device,
                    NULL, NULL, NULL);
  cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue( context,
                         device,
                         0, NULL );
  // 4. Perform runtime source compilation, and obtain kernel entry point.
  cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource( context,
                          1,
                          &source,
                          NULL, NULL );
  clBuildProgram( program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL );
  cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel( program, "memset", NULL );
  // 5. Create a data buffer.
  cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer( context,
                  CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, ...);

  // 6. Launch the kernel. Let OpenCL pick the local work size.

  size_t KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE = NWITEMS;
  clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(buffer), (void*) &buffer);
  clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( queue,
              kernel,
              1,
              NULL,
              &global_work_size,
              NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  clFinish( queue );
  // 7. Look at the results via synchronous buffer map.
  cl_uint *ptr;
  ptr = (cl_uint *) clEnqueueMapBuffer( queue,
                    buffer,
                    CL_TRUE,
                    CL_MAP_READ,
                    0,
                    NWITEMS * sizeof(cl_uint),
                    0, NULL, NULL, NULL );
  int i;

  for(i=0; i < NWITEMS; i++)
    printf("%d %d\n", i, ptr[i]);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _directories are declared invalid_ ?

Comment: The compiler/IDE sends a message that goes something like "Dev C++ has detected invalid libraries. Do you want to delete them? Only click no if you are absolutely certain about what you are doing?"